# Differences in Core Reporting API metrics due to users metric

Tags: google-analytics, api, users

When I used the Google Analytics Core Reporting API to make queries to retrieve data from a GA view I saw quite some big changes in metrics such as sessions, transactions and number of newusers in comparison to the GA UI. Finally I found out that it was due to the fact that I included the number of users in my query. When I removed that, all metrics returned exactly the same numbers as in the GA UI. Now my question is, does someone know why this is the case?

Query:
  Dim's: date, keyword
  Metrics: sessions, newUsers, transactions, transactionRevenue, users

Answer (score 1):

There are two calculations for Users in GA:

a) pre-calculated data - for standard reports (without segments)

b) calculated on the fly - custom reports, API, etc.

How the Users metric is calculated: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en